# Dotnetnuke, Working Locally, Cannot see host pages (I can see admin pages)

Tags: configuration, localhost, dotnetnuke

I cannot see host pages but I can see admin pages. Please help.

Details of my situation are below:

1. I have migrated my DNN 5.06.01 site from production to local.
2. I hooked it up in IIS 7 to http://localhost:8081/.
3. Because I could not initially see the site, I needed to manually add the portal aliases in the sql db.
4. I have added "localhost:8081", "https://localhost:8081" and "http://192.168.4.47" to my portal aliases table.
5. The site is running a certificate on the production server (I mention this to ask if there is anything that needs to be done locally to the setting / web.config).

Let me know if there's anything else you need to know in order to make some determination.

Comment: Stupid q but got to ask - are you logged in as the HOST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to "unsecure" your tabs with this:

update tabs
set IsSecure = 0

This will switch SSL off on ALL your pages, including host pages.

Comment: Thanks but where do I go to do this? SQL Database? The website admin panel? The code? You'll be a lifesaver if this is the fix! ( :

Comment: I opened up the dbo.Tabs in Sql. Here's something curious which I noticed: In the PortalID column all rows have a value of either 0, 2 or 3 EXCEPT for ALL Host tabs. They have a value of NULL. Just thought I would add this.

Comment: I also see the IsSecure column in the dbo.Tabs. Is it fine to change the value from True to False right there?

Comment: Thanks for the help! This was like jumping through hoops of fire. And I want to note that there is no documentation for this issue on dotnetnuke. This would be quite helpful since I saw many unresolved posts on the web, regarding this topic.